# Calling Conventions in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, fortran, calling-convention

I have a fortran DLL built in the CVF convention and my c++ code built using cdecl calling convention to get the stuff it needs from my DLL. I checked in my c++ code obj files and the symbols are '_*imp*_variable'. Then in my fortran dll the symbol shows up as 'variable'. I got some linker errors (unresolved external symbol _*imp*_variable), is it because c++ is looking for '_*imp*_variable' exactly as is in my DLL? Or does VS cdecl calling convention just adds stuff weirdly but it knows to look for 'variable'?

Comment: Doesn't have anything to do with calling conventions.  Your C++ code is seeing "__declspec(dllimport)" for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefix `__imp__` is added by `__declspec(dllimport)` storage-class attribute. It means that object or function is imported from DLL using import library (usually created by linker on DLL build). Make sure you added such library to your project.

If for unknown reason you don't have import lib or DLL sources take a look here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131313

Comment: Ok. That makes more sense now but I made sure the library was added to my project and the linker errors are still there. I dumpbin-ed the dll and the obj files and the symbols are all there why can't my linker see them?

Comment: Check the linker command line and make sure the library is here within correct path.

Comment: Yeap I have checked that too. I posted another question regarding the build architectures of both the fortran and c++ stuff. That could possibly be why?